# People search results not reflecting profile

Tags: 2010, people-search

Our SharePoint 2010 site is back to synchronizing user attributes from Active Directory.  On a few users I've tested by removing/changing their departments and after triggering a sync the profile is updated.  But when I search by department, the user (where I have removed their department) still shows up.  Is there another sync that must be performed?  If so then where?

[image: User profile, no department listed]

[image: search results based on department still show the users]

Comment: I seem to remember that the search crawl also needs to go through at least an incremental (possibly a full) for the search results to update. 

Can you initiate a full-crawl to see if this is indeed the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you also run at least Incremental search crawl after profile update for the content source containing source starting with address sps3://, where  is the URL for the Web application where you deployed the My Sites site collection.

Comment: Looks like that's what I missed